# How to define this sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find a way to define this sequence but I don't know how to:

{1,1,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1,...}

It starts from 1, iterates from 1 to 1, then back to 1, then it iterates from 1 to 2, then back to 1, then it iterates from 1 to 3, then back to 1, so on and so forth.

How will one define this sequence?

What I think is: $a_{n} = \{\{{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Is it a valid sequence?

Comment: can you define this sequence yourself ? how do you compute the 2000th term ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to compute the 2000th term..

Comment: so you don't know how the sequence is constructed, hence you cannot define it, and your question means nothing.

Comment: So there is no way to define the sequence I have written? I'm trying to come up with a sequence who's subsequences are convergent to for all natural numbers k. For example, a sequence which has subsequences convergent to 1,2,3,4,5,6....

Comment: to define what sequence ? you didn't write a sequence, you only wrote  the $N$ first terms. but you didn't say what are the $\ldots$ for. $ \ \ $ is $1,\ldots$ a notation to say that the sequence is then constant equal to $1$ ? "defining what are the $\ldots$ for" is precisely what is "defining a sequence"

Comment: Yes I get that, I just put the $...$ in there to show that we can continue with the sequence.

Comment: with WHAT sequence ? you don't understand what is a sequence ? when it is finite you can list each term, but when it is NOT you HAVE TO define an algorithm for constructing it.

Comment: Please calm down. That was the whole point of the question. I'm trying to figure out an algorithm for this sequence, which is what I needed help doing.

Comment: the whole point is that if you "have an infinite sequence in head" then you have in head is in fact "an algorithm for constructing it" and asking for "an algorithm for constructing it"  is meaningless (since you already have it...)

Answer (score 0):

One can actually write down a formula for the $m$-th term of the sequence.

Let the sequence be $\langle a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\rangle$. Clearly it comes in blocks:

$$\langle 1,\color{red}{1,2,1},1,2,3,2,1,\color{red}{1,2,3,4,3,2,1},1,2,\ldots\rangle\;.$$

If we number the blocks $B_0,B_1,B_2,\ldots\,$, block $B_n$ is $\langle a_{n^2},a_{n^2+1},\ldots,a_{n^2+2n}\rangle$, a block of $2n+1$ terms. The middle term of the block is $a_{n^2+n}$, and it’s not hard to check that $a_{n^2+n}=n+1$. Now consider the behavior of $|n-k|$ and $n+1-|n-k|$ as $k$ runs through the integers from $0$ through $2n$:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
k:&0&1&2&\ldots&n-1&n&n+1&\ldots&2n-1&2n\\
|n-k|:&n&n-1&n-2&\ldots&1&0&1&\ldots&n-1&n\\
n+1-|n-k|:&1&2&3&\ldots&n&n+1&n&\ldots&2&1
\end{array}$$

The numbers in the bottom row are exactly $a_{n^2+k}$ for $k=0,\ldots,2n$, the terms in block $B_n$. Thus, if $n$ is a non-negative integer, and $k$ is an integer such that $0\le k\le 2n$, then

$$a_{n^2+k}=n+1-|n-k|\;.$$

Given some non-negative integer $m$, can we find $n$ and $k$ so that $m=n^2+k$, with $0\le k\le 2n$? Yes: $n=\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor$, and $k=m-n^2$. Finally, then, we have the formula

$$\begin{align*}
a_m&=\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor+1-\left|\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor-\left(m-\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor^2\right)\right|\\
&=\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor+1-\left|\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor-m+\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor^2\right|\\
&=\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor+1-\big|\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{m}\right\rfloor+1\right)-m\,\big|\;.
\end{align*}$$